# Best way to load a globally usable library in jspm

Tags: javascript, materialize, jspm, systemjs

I am new to jspm. I want to use `materialize-css` in my project. I think the ideal way of using it is that after installing with jspm (`jspm install npm:materialize-css`) using it must be something like this (in my `index.html`):

```
System.import("materialize-css");
System.import("app");
```

The question is what is the proper way of importing and using a library that is globally usable in all of my application and have css and javascript? Such as `bootstrap`, `material-design-lite` or `materialize-css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to access the lib via the global/window object then you could import it in the index.html like you described it.
But you should make sure that it is loaded before you import your app module:

```
System.import("materialize-css").then(() => {
  System.import("app"); 
});
```